# Lag with very small floating point numbers?

Tags: performance, floating-point, numbers, lag

So, I made a simple fluid dynamics simulation with XNA, and I get very accurate wave-like behaviors. But when the waves get smaller and smaller, and at some point reach amplitudes of -4.0E-43 and less, the application starts to lag horribly. Does c# switch to some stupid rounding algorithm or something ? I've not observed any NaN's and I don't get any exceptions. Oh, the simulation loops runs in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

C# is not the culprit here. [Denormal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) are.

These are numbers with magnitudes between 0 and 2<sup>-126</sup> (1.175494351e-38) which are not stored in the standard (or 'normal') floating-point format. In fact, they are actually stored as fixed point numbers with a multiplier of 2<sup>-149</sup>.

Because they are rare and require different algorithms, operations involving denormal numbers are not optimized to the same degree as normal operations, if at all.